# Realising a drawing canvas in managed c++?

Tags: c#, c++, canvas, visual-studio-2012, drawing

How can a drawing canvas be realised in managed C++ (C++/CLI). I want to be able to "draw" on a [PictureBox object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox?view=netcore-3.1) by leftclicking the mouse and simulatneous moving the mouse. The PictureBox is cleared with white color and i want to draw with Black pixels.

Comment: What is a "drawing panel"? Do you mean the actual screen canvas where you're able to draw something? Or some toolbar (tool or color palette)?

Comment: Yeah i mean the screen canvas were i can draw. Maybe a color Palette too but thats extensional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*First of all, consider this an exception. While it's perfectly fine to ask for help with assignments and homework related stuff here (just make sure to mention it), you should really try to show some code or work you've done already. Don't just go like "I need some code, thanks." because that's not how this site is meant to work.*

**Please don't just copy and paste this code. Understand it first, then use it or apply what you've learned to your own code.**

**Back to the actual problem:** There are multiple ways to approach this, but the basic concept is always the same (even if you try to create some vector drawing program). The following lines ommit classes and namespaces for readability. If you keep the standard `using` directives, this shouldn't be an issue for you (most stull will be in `System.Drawing`). Note that I'll implement everything directly into the form. You could as well create a custom user control for this (which might be the better/cleaner approach).

First you'll need some control to actually display your drawing. Using the standard control `PictureBox` is perfectly fine for this.
Next you'll need some image to actually draw to. Add a private `Bitmap` member to your user form.
In this example we'll use the mouse cursor to draw a line. A line is always drawn between the previous position of the cursor and the current position. Due to this we'll have to store the previous position in a `Point`.
Given the previous two points, you'll need the following two members somewhere in your form (or user control):

```
private Bitmap bitmap;
private Point oldPosition;
```

In your form's `Load` event you'll have to create the `Bitmap` object. I'm also using `Graphics` to clear the `Bitmap` to white and then display it using the `PictureBox`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        g.Clear(Color.White);
    pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
}
```

Next up, we'll have to reset the previous cursor position, whenever the user clicks somewhere in the `PictureBox`. For this I add a very simple `MouseDown` event to it:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    oldPosition = e.Location;
}
```

Last but not least, the actual drawing happens in an `MouseMove` event. For this to work properly, you'll have to do one check and three working steps:

- Determine whether the user actually wants to draw (is the left mouse button pressed?).
- Draw the line into the bitmap.
- Update the previous cursor position to the new position.
- Display the results.

The code for this could look like this:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, oldPosition, e.Location);
        oldPosition = e.Location;
        pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
    }
}
```

If everything works as expected, you should be able to draw freehandedly on your `PictureBox`:

[image: Example form screenshot]

Comment: thank you for your fast answer. I'm new at Stackoverflow so next time ill ask my question more specifically^^ isn't your code c#? i got the white bmp on the picturebox work  but it seems like the drawline method doesnt support this kind of locations... any ideas?     `Pen^ blackPen = gcnew Pen( Color::Black,3.0f );
    if (e->Button == System::Windows::Forms::MouseButtons::Left)
             {
    Graphics^ g = Graphics::FromImage(bitmap);
    g->DrawLine(blackPen,oldPosition,e->Location);
    oldPosition = e->Location;
    pictureBox1->Image = bitmap;
    }`

Comment: ok nvm i fixed it thx. 4 ur help :))